# Docker Windows Server 2016 switch to linux container

Tags: windows, docker, windows-server-2016

I Installed docker on Windows Server 2016.

ike described here:
https://store.docker.com/editions/enterprise/docker-ee-server-windows?tab=description

```
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Force
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
Restart-Computer -Force
```

Now the container runs per default as windows container but i want to have it running linux container.

On My desktop machine I've a tray icon where i can switch this. but on there server there isn't one

So what do i have to do tochange to linux container or how to get the tray icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this question, Michael Friis [indicates](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-on-windows-2017-how-to-switch-do-linux-container/30648/3) on the OP's post that the new edge channel includes experimental support:

> The new edge installer supports installing on Windows Server 2016:
>   https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#download-docker-for-windows27

Comment: The link you give does not lead to anything about an edge installer.

Comment: Yes it looks like this post is out of date now, since it's nearly four years old at this point. I believe that functionality moved to Mirantis' Windows containers some time back.

Answer (score 2):

Its intended behavior

> Ok. So far as I know. The Linux containers feature is only available
> on "Docker For Windows" on Win 10. Not normal Docker on WS2016.
> ...
>
> Because "linux containers" on Win10 does some smoke and mirrors with a Linux VM. >Not a production solution

https://twitter.com/Gentlehag/status/849313687429140481